# Can I use Activity Group to show two activities at the same time in Android?

Tags: android, android-activity, activitygroup

I'd like to show two different activities at the same time on the screen. I was under the impression that one may achieve it using `ActivityGroup`. Is that so?

### UPDATE

I tried it this way:

```
layout = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.wrapper_layout);

LocalActivityManager mgr = getLocalActivityManager();

Intent intent = new Intent(this, BenchMarker.class);

Window w = mgr.startActivity("BenchMarkerA", intent);
View wd = w != null ? w.getDecorView() : null;

if(wd != null) {
    layout.addView(wd);
}
```

But got a `NullPointerException` thrown by `ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, I **can**. I'll write the solution later these days.

### UPDATE

Here's how to do it.

First, you'd need a suitable layout, say *res/layout/multiview.xml*:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:id="@+id/multiview_layout">
    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/my_view_1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1">
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_weight="1"
        android:id="@+id/my_view_2">
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

And in your main activity that will play the role of a launcher:

```
public class MyMultiViewActivity extends ActivityGroup {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.multiview);
        layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.multiview_layout);
        layout_s1 = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.my_view_1);
        layout_s2 = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.my_view_2);

        LocalActivityManager mgr = getLocalActivityManager();

        layout_s1.addView((mgr.startActivity("MyOtherActivityInstance1", new Intent(this, MyOtherActivity.class))).getDecorView());
        layout_s2.addView((mgr.startActivity("MyOtherActivityInstance2", new Intent(this, MyOtherActivity.class))).getDecorView());
    }

    LinearLayout layout;
    LinearLayout layout_s1;
    LinearLayout layout_s2;
}
```

Comment: hi albus, if you had found the solution so please post the solution as i m stack in this problem.

Comment: Yes, I have. I'll write it here no sooner than next weekend as I'm very busy right now.

Comment: Hi Gapipro. Yes, it's rather simple to do. I'll update my answer as soon as I've got the time, which may very well be this weekend.

Comment: @Veer, sorry about that, I totally forgot. I've updated my answer, so would you be so kind as to remove your downvote? Thanks!